# How to add Line breaks in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I display HTML text that has line breaks and have those line breaks maintained?

```
public void OnGet()
{
    ViewData["Msg"] = "Hello World \n Hello World \n Hello World \n Hello World";
}
```

The above is straight text with embedded line feeds

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
 }

<textarea rows="4" asp-for="@ViewData["Msg"]" style="width:100%">ViewData["Msg"]</textarea>

Message : @ViewData["Msg"]
```

The text views correctly in the textarea but not as straight HTML `Message : @ViewData["Msg"]`. I just want to display static text and not having to add it to a predefined `textarea`. Below shows the result of the code below:

[image]

Comment: HTML doesn't have line breaks. While you can use `<br>` it's *far* better to use `<div>` tags with the proper style. `ViewData["Msg"]` doesn't have to be a string, it can be an array. Neither do you have to use `ViewData`, a better option would be to use a model class with an array property

Comment: BTW what you posted looks like Razor Pages, not MVC. In that case any properties in your PageModel can be used by your Page directly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the code I used I just scraped up together just for this post

Comment: You mean it's fake code? You don't need ViewBag at all in Razor Pages while `OnGet` won't work in MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace "\n" by [line break](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) tag:

```cs
public void OnGet()
{
    var text = " Hello World \n Hello World \n Hello World \n Hello World".Replace("\n","<br>");
    ViewData["Msg"] = $"<div>{text}</div>";
}
```

On the view side use [Html.Raw()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.raw?view=aspnetcore-7.0) helper to render without HTML-encoding:

```xml
@Html.Raw(@ViewData["Msg"])
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jackdaw ! That worked !

Comment: Note this would also make your `textarea` element contain `<br>` tags which may not be what you really want. Another solution is to add `white-space: pre;` CSS to the element containing the text, which tells the browser to respect the line breaks.